# dynamically changing picture box

Tags: c#, .net

i dynamically create several picture box, and EventHandler. when user click on pictureBox, the program should delete tрis item. (the item that the user selected)

i try do

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sunduki; i++)
        {
            PictureBox PBObj = new PictureBox();
            PBObj.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(i * 100, 101);
            PBObj.Name = "pictureBox" + i.ToString();
            PBObj.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(108, 80);
            PBObj.TabIndex = i;
            PBObj.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"syndyk1.jpg");
            PBObj.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
            PBObj.Click += new System.EventHandler(pb_Click); 
            PB.Add(PBObj);
            Controls.Add(PB[PB.Count - 1]);}
```

and in pb_click

```
private void pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { PB[this].Visible = false; }
```

but i have an error. (PB is the list with pictureBox)

Comment: What is the error? what do you mean by delete? what are you using? wpf? winforms? how do you delete?

Comment: If PB is array of picture box then you must supply the index. Better to add more details in question.

Comment: i useing winForms. error: can not convert Form1 to int

Comment: Just like Hassan said, if this is an array you must use an index.  The error is trying to use `this` (`Form1`) and convert it to an `int` which is the index.  Supply the index and you will hide the Picturebox

Comment: can't loop through, because I don't know the number of the current element

Comment: So you are going to need to supply more code.  Supply the part where you generate this picturebox array.  In the `eventhandler` for each individual picturebox can you not say `this.Visible = false`?

Comment: Normally when your control subscribe to `EventHandler` the sender object and event args could be sent. Also `this` means you are referring to current form instance. You cannot use it instead of index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender argument will be the object that has been clicked, in this case it is the PictureBox object.

```
private void pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   var pb = sender as PictureBox;
   if(pb != null)
   {
       pb.Visible = false;
   }
}
```

Note: This doesn't delete the picture box, but makes it not visible. Controls deletion is handled by the disposal of the form.